# SQL Server agent Jobs and SSIS Project

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2008, sql-job

My SSIS package creates xls files to a folder. When I execute the project in my local machine that works fine. When I execute the job it creates a file that doesn't exist.

What could be the problem?

The jobs says that:

> Source: Send Mail Task Send Mail Task      Description: Either the
>   file
>   "\\bpptvwdw0000001\DTSXs\SubscricaoDirComercial\CustomSubscriptions\dw_PropAprovadasAConcretizar__20200408.xls"
>   does not exist or you do not have permissions to access the file."

That means the file does not exist or you do not have permissions to access the file, but when I execute it from my machine the project doesn't create that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the account running your job does not have rights to that folder.